# Percentage label to 100% Stack chart tried "mutate" but did not work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to plot a 100% Stack chart with %age labels in ggplot2 . Attaching the code here with the data I am working with . The question may be a duplicate but have tried the solutions but giving errors or showing the same plot as below.

dput output :

```
structure(list(Category = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("_", 
"1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("IL1_Flag", "IL2_Flag", "IL3_Flag", "IL4_Flag", 
"IL5_Flag"), class = "factor"), value = c(21, 17, 16, 219, 20, 
17, 15, 207, 20, 15, 15, 204, 20, 15, 15, 202, 20, 15, 15, 208
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .Names = c("Category", "variable", 
"value"), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)

#Plotting the 100% Stacked Chart
ggplot() + geom_bar(
  aes(y = value, x = Category, fill = variable),
  data = agg_melt,
  stat = "identity" ,
  position = "fill"
) + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +labs(x="Category" , y= "Percentage (%)")
```

I have used this code to try to replace the values but it is not working.

```
agg_melt %>%
  mutate(Percentage = value / sum(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = Category,
    y = Percentage,
    fill = `variable`,
    label = paste0(round(Percentage * 1000), "%")
  )) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill",
           color = "black" ,
           stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(position = position_fill(vjust = .5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

Can anybody help in getting the percentage labels to them ?
[image]

Comment: Minimal in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) means users should post minimal code to reproduce the problem. Also, please add your data to post using `dput` (eg. `dput(agg_melt)`) instead of linking to google drive (this way your example will be reproducible after data will get taken from google drive).

Comment: @PoGibas : I have included the dput output and removed unecessary code.

Comment: So your question is - How to put percent label above each color?

Comment: Yes , I want to show %age label for the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the percentages in your dataframe before passing the results to ggplot.

Here, I assume you want the percentage within each category (though if you want the overall percentage, just comment out the `group_by()` line):

```
library(dplyr)

agg_melt <- agg_melt %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate(p = value / sum(value))

> head(agg_melt)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups: Category [4]
  Category variable value     p
  <fctr>   <fctr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 1        IL1_Flag  21.0 0.208
2 2        IL1_Flag  17.0 0.215
3 3        IL1_Flag  16.0 0.211
4 4        IL1_Flag 219   0.211
5 1        IL2_Flag  20.0 0.198
6 2        IL2_Flag  17.0 0.215
```

Pass this modified dataframe to ggplot. You can also specify the common aesthetic parameters in the top level `ggplot()` rather than inside individual geoms:

```
ggplot(data = agg_melt,
       aes(y = value, 
           x = Category, 
           label = percent(p),
           fill = variable)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") + 
  geom_text(position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  labs(x = "Category", 
       y = "Percentage (%)")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! @Z.Lin . This is exactly how I want the graph :)